# Assigning variables to user input in C++

Tags: c++

This is the code I'm currently working on in C++. As you can tell it's a choose your own adventure game. I'm trying to figure out how to create two different paths via user input. Any help or adjustments to the code would be helpful. Code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string name;
int gender;

int main()
{

//Name prompt for future reference
    cout << "Hello. I want to play a game. You'll be going on a";
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << "wild ride with it's own ups and downs.";
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << "To start out what is your name?";
    cout << std::endl;
   cin >> name;

//Determining Which Gender the player identifies with
    cout << "Perfect " <<name;
    cout << ". We shall ask a few more questions to determine";
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << "path will be best suited for you.";
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << "What is your gender? If Male enter 1 If Female enter 2";
    cout << std::endl;
    cin >> gender;
    cout << std::endl;



//Now we shall start the path determined by the chosen gender
    if(gender == 1) 
    cout << "Fantastic! You're a male so that means you are very simple. With that being said let us get started.";
    else
    cout << "Hmm... This seems to be a little difficult our systems indicate that putting you into situations seems a little bit more... complex. Never the matter. Let us get started!";
    cout << std::endl;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Help with what?  Your `if(gender == 1)` does what you ask.

Comment: What *actual* problem are you having?  What input are you giving it, and how does the resulting output differ from what you expect.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to make a path for (gender == 1) and (gender == 2) without spamming if and else statements

Comment: Such as if you chose (gender == 1) I can have a separate story line Versus (gender == 2)

Comment: You probably want an `if (gender == 1) { … } else if (gender == 2) { … } else { … }` or a `switch (gender) { case 1: …; break; case 2: …; break; default: … }` construct.

Answer (score -4):

You must use brackets (`{` and `}`) around your if-statements.

**WRONG:**

```
if(gender == 1) 
    cout << "Fantastic! You're a male so that means you are very simple. With that being said let us get started.";
    else
    cout << "Hmm... This seems to be a little difficult our systems indicate that putting you into situations seems a little bit more... complex. Never the matter. Let us get started!";
    cout << std::endl;
```

---

---

**RIGHT**

```
if(gender == 1) 
{
    cout << "Fantastic! You're a male so that means you are very simple. With that being said let us get started.";
}
else
{
    cout << "Hmm... This seems to be a little difficult our systems indicate that putting you into situations seems a little bit more... complex. Never the matter. Let us get started!";
}
cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: You don't have to use them if there is only one statement.  And in this particular case, your suggested solution does not print a newline character in the `gender == 1` case.

Comment: Every professional coding environment requires them.   Lack of brackets can lead to subtle, hard to spot bugs.   I would never trust a developer who does not use brackets.

Comment: This is nonsense. good luck not trusting GNU developers.
http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Formatting

edit: also google style guide: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Conditionals

Comment: It's a matter of taste, not “right” or “wrong”.  But at the very least, move the `cout << std::endl` out of the `else` case so the code does what the OP's code did.

Comment: [Apple's "goto fail"](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/) security bug was largely due to missing brackets.  And it was GNU code.